# Visual Studio 2019: "delete existing files" option in publish profile disappeared

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've just updated my copy of `Visual Studio` to version `16.10`, and something weird happened: when publishing a project, the "delete existing files" option is not editable anymore. You can see it but when opening the edit dialog there is no checkbox to edit it.

Here's a screenshot for clarification:
[image]

Is this a bug, or is it intended?
Is there an alternative way to set that option, or is it just not supported anymore?

Comment: Disappeared again in VS 2022. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just updated Visual Studio to version 16.11 and it seems they fixed it, the option is back in the settings menu:

[image]

Comment: Odd, i just updated to 16.11.3 and my options do not include this either

Comment: I tested on VS 16.11.5 and it seems that only ASP.NET projects (doesn't matter if .NET Core or .NET Framework) provide that option. All other kinds of .NET Core projects (Console, WPF, WinForms) use the same Publishing tab and *.pubxml format, but show another dialog when clicking on "Show all settings" (I tested only with .NET Core 3.1). .NET Framework projects (except ASP.NET) use a completely different publishing wizard.

Comment: @MartinSchneider: That's so weird... I wonder why. Do you know where would be the appropriate place to ask Microsoft about this supposed anomaly?

Answer (score 6):

I initially tried adding `<DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>` to the pubxml file (under the Properties folder in VS).   Unfortunately, this only update the Publish dialog but had no apparent effect on the publishing process.

For my workaround, I opted to add this to build event:  `del /S /Q $(TargetDir)publish`. It clears out my publish directory on each build - you'll have to alter "$(TargetDir)publish" to fit your needs. The workaround is slight overkill, but arguably a better choice since there is less chance of the published files being picked up after a recent change/build.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, upvoted it but I will leave the answer open for now in case someone can provide a more "official" way to fix this (or confirmation that the option is gone for good and we should use a workaround from now on)

Comment: Adding `<DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>` worked for me on visual studio 2019 preview

Answer (score 0):

Open .pubxml file in a text editor (mine was in Properties\PublishProfiles) and update/add the key DeleteExistingFiles to True.

Answer (score 0):

I think regarding @Phil's answer, the 2 actions are doing different things.

### 1. DeleteExistingFiles

This will delete existing files on the web server when you actually deploy.  I don't see any documentation about this setting from Microsoft which is frustrating.  This same *feature* is available when you publish your application to a Web Deploy Package and use the Import feature in IIS to import the application.  You will get a prompt like this:
[image]

This is the same as `DeleteExistingFiles` in a publish profile.

### 2. Publish directory

Deleting the `publish` directory is a different thing.  The publish directory is a working directory of the `msbuild /t:Publish` or `msbuild /t:Package` commands.  Basically what is in the publish directory is what ends up in the ZIP file used for a web deploy package or a publish profile.  You can get issues during publish process with incorrect files in the publish directory.  For example, https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/issues/157.
Unfortunately there is no way to delete or clean the publish directory with the existing msbuild or dotnet cli commands:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/5972.

Fun times.  So @Phil's `del` command is what we are left with.